# Word for both questions and answers

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm preparing for an exam by answering some questions in an assignment, however, I am writing the answers in the same document as the questions. I would therefore like to name that file appropriately.

- `Solution` seems misleading, as the file does not contain only solutions, but the questions as well!
- `Assignment` seems like it's the opposite of one above, and therefore doesn't fit either.

**What word is used to describe both questions and the corresponding answers?**

The current name of the file is `questions and answers`, which is a bit too verbose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about "exam review"?  That suggests questions with answers to me.

Also, "Q&A"is a valid file name for a Word document in Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

"*Practice exam*" - would that fit the bill?

Answer (score 0):

You  may use **explanation**,  or **key**  if the questions are multiple choice.